# How to plot sorted barplot in plolty3.10

Tags: python, plotly

I have been trying to plot sorted barplot in plotly for some stores sales data, but whatever I try it gives me the unsorted data. How to plot the sorted barplot using plotly.

NOTE:
https://community.plot.ly/t/sort-bars-in-bar-chart-by-value-and-have-each-bar-with-a-different-color/14562

Did not worked for me.

## Data

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


import plotly
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import plot, iplot, init_notebook_mode
init_notebook_mode(connected=False)

print([(x.__name__,x.__version__) for x in [np, pd,plotly]])

url = "https://github.com/bhishanpdl/Datasets/blob/master/store_item_demand/train_store_item_demand.csv?raw=true"
df = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates=['date'],index_col=['date'])
```

## Using pandas (gives sorted barplot)

```py
df1 = df.groupby('store')['sales'].sum().sort_values()
df1.plot.bar()
```

## Using plotly3.10 (gives unsorted barplot) (How to fix this?)

```
def barplot(x,y):
    data = [go.Bar(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        marker={
            'color': y,
            'colorscale': 'Reds'
        }
    )]

    layout = {
        'xaxis': {
            'tickvals': x,
            'ticktext': ['store ' + str(i) for i in x],
            'tickangle': 40
        }
    }

    fig = go.FigureWidget(data=data, layout=layout)

    return iplot(fig)


# plot

df1 = df.groupby('store')['sales'].sum().sort_values()
x = df1.index.values
y = df1.values

barplot(x,y)
```

## outputs

[image]

[image]

## Question

How to get sorted barplot using plotly3.10 ?

## Related link

https://community.plot.ly/t/sort-bars-in-bar-chart-by-value-and-have-each-bar-with-a-different-color/14562

Did not work for me.

Comment: You want the bars sorted by height or by store number?

Comment: @nicolaskruchten by height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct key to use for this is `layout.xaxis.categoryorder`, with the value `"total ascending"`, but it only applies when the `layout.xaxis.type` is `"category"`. This happens automatically if your `x` array contains strings, but if your `x` contains only numbers you'll have to set it manually.

Here is a version of your `barplot` function as recommended:

```
def barplot(x,y):
    data = [go.Bar(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        marker={
            'color': y,
            'colorscale': 'Reds'
        }
    )]

    layout = {
        'xaxis': {
            'tickvals': x,
            'ticktext': ['store ' + str(i) for i in x],
            'tickangle': 40,
            'type': "category",
            'categoryorder': 'total ascending'
        }
    }

    fig = go.FigureWidget(data=data, layout=layout)

    return iplot(fig)
```

Comment: I tried: `    layout = {
        'xaxis': {
            'tickvals': x,
            'ticktext': ['store ' + str(i) for i in x],
            'tickangle': 40,
            'categoryorder': 'category ascending',
            'categoryarray': [x for _, x in sorted(zip(y, x))]
        }
    }`  But it gives the same result.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.  Here x-axis is stores names and it is string type. whatever I put in `categoryorder`  but unfortunately it did not worked for me.

Comment: sorry, it should be `"total ascending"` not `"values ascending"`... I updated the answer.

Comment: there's no need to manually work with `categoryarray` or anything, just add the two lines I added inside the `layout` object assignment

Comment: I should add that in your function above, the `x` array is not an array of strings: you're setting the tick labels to strings but that's not quite the same thing so you need to either add the "store" prefix into the `x` array directly or set the `xaxis.type` attribute.

Comment: Sorry, it failed again. 
ValueError: 
    Invalid value of type 'builtins.str' received for the 'categoryorder' property of layout.xaxis
        Received value: 'total ascending'

    The 'categoryorder' property is an enumeration that may be specified as:
      - One of the following enumeration values:
            ['trace', 'category ascending', 'category descending',
            'array']

Comment: [('plotly', '3.6.1')]

Comment: Ah, well your question says 3.10 :)

Comment: Sorry, my laptop has plotly3.10 and google colaboratoy has default plotly 3.6.1, I tested your code in google colaboratory.

Comment: OK, please accept the answer if it works in 3.10 ;)

Comment: I would happily do it, its a great help. But still do you have suggestions to adapt the code to plotly3.6? Since I frequently use google colab and it has default plotly3.6, if I have to use other versions each time I have to pip install it.

Comment: No, sorry: we added that feature in 3.10 :)

Comment: Well... if you create a different question for 3.6 I can maybe think of something. But it's one-question/one-answer on StackOverflow.