# How to sort bar charts in plotly3.6?

Tags: python, plotly

I have plotly3.6 installed in my office computer, which I can not upgrade.
And I was trying to make sorted bar plots but it is failing to do so.

How can I do so?

My attempt:

```py
def barplot(x,y):
    data = [go.Bar(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        marker={
            'color': y,
            'colorscale': 'Reds'
        }
    )]

    layout = {
        'xaxis': {
            'tickvals': x,
            'ticktext': [str(i) for i in x],
            'tickangle': 40,
            'type': "category",
            'categoryorder': 'category ascending'
        }
    }

    fig = go.FigureWidget(data=data, layout=layout)

    return iplot(fig)


# plot
x = list('abcde')
y = [20,10,5,8,9]


barplot(x,y)
```

Related links:
(This only works for plotly3.10, does not work for 3.6)
[How to plot sorted barplot in plolty3.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57642439/how-to-plot-sorted-barplot-in-plolty3-10/57648800#57648800)

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version of your function which does this... basically you just pre-sort the `x` and `y` values that you pass into `go.Bar()`. Because `x` is a list of strings in this case, the `xaxis.type` is inferred to be `"category"` and the order of the categories is by default the order in which the `x` list is provided, so there's no need to fiddle with `tickvals` or `ticktext`.

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import iplot

def barplot(x,y):
    sorted_y = sorted(y)
    sorted_x = [str(j) for i,j in sorted(zip(y,x))]

    data = [go.Bar(
        x=sorted_x,
        y=sorted_y,
        marker={
            'color': y,
            'colorscale': 'Reds'
        }
    )]

    fig = go.FigureWidget(data=data)

    return iplot(fig)


# plot
x = list('abcde')
y = [20,10,5,8,9]


barplot(x,y)
```